# Worklight App reloads broken in galaxy tablet

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a application developed with worklight version 6.1 that uses a anchor tag which when clicked opens the phone dialer with the given number. When we press the back button from the app reloads instead of coming from background .In most of the android device ,the above problem didnt arise except in android galaxy s2.Have any solution for it.The anchoring tag is given below

```
<a href="tel:9929828747">
```

Comment: What is the Android OS used in this device compared to other devices? Also, try using the **pause** event API method to see if you have indeed entered the background: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#pause

Comment: @Idan Adar Galaxy s2 is using the android 4.0.

Comment: @Idan Adar I try your suggestion and the pause event is been calling but the worklight app reloads when the home button is clicked.

Comment: You mean when you go back to the foreground, not when the home button is clicked... and when you say reloads, how do you know it is a reload? What are you experiencing?

Comment: @Idan Adar Because it starts from the ibm splash screen but i want to be in the current page where i left to background

Comment: This happens also if you do not tap the href, rather simply tap the home button and then the app icon again? Or does this happen ONLY when tapping the href?

Comment: @Idan Adar Both the times it happens(tap the home button and then the app icon or tap the href)

Comment: Sounds like a device issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some settings in the developer options (Settings --> Developer options) in Android that might cause this behavior.
For example the "Don't keep activities" is on or the "Background processes limit" is too low.